# JDBC, Prepared Statement getInt() returns 0

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

In my DB every question has a valid questionID (primary Key) and categoryID (foreign Key to category table).
The problem is: in the Result Set for every question both IDs are 0 instead of what's written in the DB. All other arguments are filled out correctly.

```
private ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
private Connection connie;
private PreparedStatement psShowQuestions;


psShowQuestions= connie.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM question");        
ResultSet rs = psShowQuestions.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
     questions.add(new Question(rs.getInt("questionID"), rs.getInt("categoryID"), rs.getString("question"), rs.getString("rightAns"), rs.getString("wrong1"), rs.getString("wrong2"), rs.getString("wrong3"), rs.getString("hint")));
}
Collections.shuffle(questions);
```

---

**Edit 1**

Here is the original code (in the post I changed the variables from German to English):

The creation of my SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `frage` (
  `frageID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kategorieID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `frage` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `richtig` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `falsch1` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `falsch2` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `falsch3` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `hinweis` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `anzFalsch` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `anzRichtig` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
private ArrayList<Frage> fragen = new ArrayList<Frage>();
private Connection connie;
private PreparedStatement psGetFragen;

ResultSet rs = psGetFragen.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
     fragen.add(new Frage(rs.getInt("frageID"), rs.getInt("kategorieID"), rs.getString("frage"), rs.getString("richtig"), rs.getString("falsch1"), rs.getString("falsch2"), rs.getString("falsch3"), rs.getString("hinweis")));
}
Collections.shuffle(fragen);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, there is a problem with the constructor. You might have not set `questionID` and `categoryID` in the constructor and therefore you are getting the default value of `int` as `0`.

Comment: Thank you.
...I added the ID parameters later and forgot to set them